# ServiceStack Social Auth and Xamarin

Tags: authentication, servicestack, xamarin, socialauth

We're using the social auth part of Servicestack to authenticate users against our API. This works like a charm using a PHP client.

My question is - what would be the best way of integrating social login that uses a servicestack API into a xamarin app?

I have used the Azure social login stuff before but that obviously wont work. How can I authenticate a user inside a xamarin app against facebook, twitter, google that can then pass that auth to my API?

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason ServiceStack won't work with your mobile application? It should as ServiceStack.Text works and the web clients work as well on both Android and iOS.

Anyways, you could always use Xamarin.Auth for authentication: http://components.xamarin.com/view/xamarin.auth

Comment: Yeah - but that doesn't give me the SS-ID I need to call my rest service. Or is there a way I haven't seen?

Comment: Have you looked into compiling the ServiceStack library into Xamarin compatible libraries or are they too web oriented?

Comment: There are servicestack dlls for the client - but that doesn't handle authenticating against FB/Twitter etc. how do I get the redirect stuff from twitter /fb to work with SS on a mobile client I guess is the q

Comment: Are your services implemented with ServiceStack? V4 (newest) or V3 (open source)? I am working on the V3 base and if you look into ServiceStack.Common.ServiceClient.Web there are two service classes Auth and AuthResponse you could possibly use in combination with Xamarin.Auth.

Comment: I'm on v4 - I'll take a look :)